# How to find path to compact database.sdf in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows, service, sql-server-ce

I have a solution with 3 projects: a WPF application, a setup and a Windows service.

In the WPF application I have a `Database.sdf` (SQL Server CE database) file. When the application is installed for example in folder X there is also the `database.sdf` file in this folder.

Now my problem is: I want to connect to this database from the Windows service, how can I find out where the application was installed so I can get the path to the `.sdf` file?

Comment: Add a `app.config` to the service and have the path to the `.sdf` as a configuration setting for the service.

Comment: Hmm? I don't get it. When I install the Setup project User can choose any folder/path he wants, so how can I write in App.conf of Windows service the path to the .sdf file when I don't know where user will install it ?

Comment: The setup project could update the `MyService.exe.config` for the service with the location of the file that the user chooses during setup.....

Answer (score 0):

You could write a registry key in HKLM during install of the WPF app, which contains the path to the database file, and the Windows Service could then read this key.